# Inserting Multiples Records into Two Columns in Sqlite Database using ContentValues

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Whenever I use the following code to insert multiple records into a table it only inserts the last initialized value.
Here's the method for inserting data into a table:

```
public long insertQuote() {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHID, 100);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.5700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 27.1833);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 26.4583);

        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.3200);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0300);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 78.0167);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 80.3173);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

In this case for the column key "KEY_LAT" I am only able to see the last initialized value "26.4583" on a S.O.P (Sys.out.println) output on logcat.

Same follows for the other column key "KEY_LON". I can see just these two records.
I suppose they're not inserted into the table as `put()` Method skips the previously `"to-be-inserted"` values and accepts the last for a particular column.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are using same key LAT and LON for all. That's being overwritten.

You should use different keys such as

```
public long insertQuote() {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHID, 100);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT1, 28.5700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT2, 28.4700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT3, 27.1833);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT4, 26.4583);

        initialValues.put(KEY_LON1, 77.3200);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON2, 77.0300);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON3, 78.0167);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON4, 80.3173);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Edit:

So you should use this approach.

```
public long insertQuote() {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_PHID, 100);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.5700);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.3200);
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4700);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0300);
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 27.1833);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 78.0167);
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 26.4583);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 80.3173);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);  
        }
```

Comment: using different "KEY_LAT1, ..KEY_LAT3.." would mean different column names. Because KEY_LAT and KEY_LON are declared as: `public String KEY_LAT = "LATS";
 public String KEY_LON = "LONS";` Here LATS and LONS are 2 different column fields in a single table. Did you mean to say that I should declare KEY_LAT1="LATS" and KEY_LAT2="LATS" and so on..?

Comment: Here's my table structure: `phID (of type integer) | LATS (of type real)| LONS (of type real)` I want all the KEY_LAT values to be in a single column named LATS and all the KEY_LON values to be in another column named LONS